# Adding packet numbers in Openflow

Tags: networking, openflow

I know that counting of packets is possible in OpenFlow, but Is it possible to attach packet numbers to each packet entering a port in Open vSwitch using a shell command?
If yes, what is the command to do so?
Regards,
Sushmita

Comment: You don't explain for which layer-3 protocol (IPv4, IPX, IPv6, AppleTalk, etc) you want to modify the packets. For example You cannot simply add anything to an IPv4 packet header. There is an Identification field in the IPv4 header that may be repurposed, but it is used when packets must be fragmented, so it may not work for you. You would also need to recalculate the Header Checksum field if you change anything in an IPv4 packet header.

Comment: I was approaching for IPv4. My idea was to add the packet number as a new 'layer' , thereby defining a new protocol.There will be an understanding between the two switches interacting with each other about the new protocol though.I am an amateur at networking  , so I don't even know if the whole idea seems foolish.

Comment: My  goal is to reorder IPv4 packets as much as possible  irrespective of the upper layers ,so that much of the processing is done withing the OpenvSwitch and not the hosts.

Comment: IP, including IPv4, has no idea of what the packet payload is, so it has no way to know what the proper ordering of the packets should be. That is really up to the higher-level protocols, and I think that trying to do it at a lower level could really cause problems. You are, or course, free to create your own protocol in which to tunnel IPv4.

Comment: Yes exactly, because IP has no idea of reordering I want to explicitly mention that as an additional layer (say between ethernet and IP layers).This additional layer can be used for the reordering purpose.

Comment: alternatively I tried to do that in Scapy by generating a custom layer between Ether and IP. But I don't know if it even makes sense to do so and if it will work with mininet and OvS.

Comment: My point is that IP has no idea in which order the data should be. Trying to implement that at lower levels may actually increase the number of out-of-order packets. Only the upper layers know what order the data should be.

Comment: If you can kindly explain how it will increase the number of out-of-order packets.

Comment: Having a device with no idea of what the real order of data should be to decide the order of the data simply cannot be accurate. The hosts on each end know what order the data should have, but the devices in between have no way to know. Also, the primary purpose of the network infrastructure devices is to forward the packets as quickly as possible. Adding processing to them defeats that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ron. It will really help me to rethink my approach.